# How to make sure the SocketChannel is really connected when using NIO?

Tags: java, selector, nio, socketchannel, broken-pipe

I'm working on a NIO client program on Android, Basically it functions well, but when the network is not avaliable(WIFI is disabled, etc), I have no idea how to distinguish the socket is 'really' connected, SocketChannel.finishConnect() always returns true even there is no avaliable network.If I try to write to a unconnected SocketChannel, an Broken pipe exception will happen.

So I wonder how to make sure the SocketChannel is really connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to write to a unconnected SocketChannel, an Broken pipe exception will happen.

Correct.

> So I wonder how to make sure the SocketChannel is really connected?

That's how. There is no API that can tell you. TCP doesn't work like that. The only way to detect a broken TCP connection is to try to use it.

Comment: thanks for reply, it seems that I have to use SocketChannel.configureBlocking(true) before socketChannel.connect(address) , So if the connection failed, a java.net.ConnectException will be thrown.

Comment: If you connect in non-blocking mode and there is a connection failure, `finishConnect()` should throw `ConnectException` too.

Comment: by the way, if the network becomes unavaliable(WIFI shut down, etc) after SocketChannel is connected, can selector dectect the broken pipe automaticly?

Comment: I tried before, but even if there is no avaliable network, finishConnect() always returns true and no exception is thrown until writing something to the channel

Comment: That's exactly what I said. The only way to detect a broken connection is to try to write to it.